# AttributeError: type object 'Player2' has no attribute 'x'

Tags: python, классы, tkinter, атрибуты

Говорит что нет атрибута x, а он есть.
Не знаю скорее всего ошибка очень глупая, но я реально не могу понять в чём дело.

Вот ошибка:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Artyom\PycharmProjects\pythonProject4\main.py", line 51, in <module>
    print(Player2.x)
          ^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: type object 'Player2' has no attribute 'x'
```

А вот мой код:

```
from tkinter import *

game = Tk()
game.title('Simple multiplayer game, it was made that show how to create multiplayer or communication this server')
game.geometry('1000x600')
game.resizable(width=False, height=False)
canvas = Canvas(game, width=1000, height=600)
canvas.place(in_=game, x=0, y=0)

class Player1:
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = 250
        self.y = 300
        self.v = 0
        self.photo = PhotoImage(file='knight.png')

    def up(self, event):
        self.v = -3

    def down(self, event):
        self.v = 3

    def stop(self, event):
        self.v = 0

class Player2:
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = 750
        self.y = 300
        self.v = 0
        self.photo = PhotoImage(file='knight.png')

    def up(self, event):
        self.v = -3

    def down(self, event):
        self.v = 3

    def stop(self, event):
        self.v = 0


def start():
    canvas.delete('all')
    canvas.create_image(Player1.x, Player1.y, image=Player1.photo)
    canvas.create_image(Player2.x, Player2.y, image=Player2.photo)


# start()

print(Player2.x)

game.mainloop()
```

Comment: Player1, Player2 - это не объекты, а классы. Вам нужно сначала создать объекты `player1 = Player1()` и `player2 = Player2()`, у них будут поля, которые вы прописали в `__init__`. В целом, нет смысла создавать два одинаковых класса с разными параметрами, можно было сделать один класс, а параметры передавать при создании объекта.

Comment: Спасибо большое

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У класса `Player2` нет атрибута `x`, этот атрибут будет только у объектов этого класса.

```
player2 = Player2()
print(player2.x)
```

Comment: Спасибо большое